# Testng ITestListener with parallel tests for skipped test

Tags: testng, appium

I'm running test automation with appium in java and I have an issue with how to catch skipped test on parallel testing.

When I was running my tests on a single device, I've always used ITestListener to catch my skipped tests and log them in my report. It was working nice until I tried to run my tests on multiple devices at the same time.

The issue come from the fact that it's a listener, and I can not pass any parameter to it (tell me if i'm wrong).

So now that I have multiple devices, I don't know how to differentiate which device is called in the method

`void onTestSkipped(ITestResult var1);`

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get object attributes from [`ITestResult`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestResult.html) and/or [`ITestContext`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestContext.html) in the listener.

You can add attributes via `@BeforeMethod` or `@AfterMethod`. See [the documentation about injection](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection).